# How do I add a variable to a dataset within a SET statement in a data step?

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a SAS data step that uses a `%do` loop to build a set statement that combines multiple files. The files have names of the form `datafile2020q1` or `datafile2021q3`, and they're each stored in libraries with names of the form `DataLibrary2020` or `DataLibrary2021`.

```
%macro processclaimsdata;
data rawclaimsdata (keep=&claimvariables.);
set
    %do yr=2019 %to 2021;
        %do qrtr=1 %to 4;
            DataLibrary&yr..datafile&yr.q&qrtr. (keep=&claimvariables.)
        %end;
    %end;
;
run;
%mend;
```

My goal is to add a variable to the dataset that has `YYYYqQ` in it, e.g., 2020q1 or 2021q3, for each dataset, so I can keep track of *which* file it came from. Is this possible by modifying my code above, or do I need to rework it to use `proc append` and/or `proc sql`?

Comment: Try adding this to your keep option: trackdsn=%sysfunc(putn(&yr., 4.)||'Q'||putn(&qrtr.,1.)

Comment: I should mention to add this to your SET statement and then add trackdsn to your keep option in your data step.

Comment: Thanks, @linstar. Why is this preferred to using the `indsname` option on the `set` statement? (See Stu's earlier answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `indsname=` option to keep track of the dataset that a row came from. Although it won't be in the format you specify, this will tell you the exact dataset name that a row came from.

The code below will create a new temporary variable in the dataset called `dsn` that stores the name of the dataset a row came from. You can add it to the dataset by assigning it to a permanent variable.

```
data want;
    set have1
        have2
        have3
    indsname=dsn;

    dsname = dsn;
run;
```

You can then use `substr()` or other string functions to snag the name of the quarter from each dataset name. For example:

`qtr = substr(dsn, -6);`

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't clear to me that I MUST use the `substr` command (or some other command) to make a permanent copy of the variable, since [`indsname` only makes a temporary variable](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/08/03/indsname-option.html). Maybe worth a short edit?

Comment: Great point. Added this to the explanation.